# Disable highlighting on side of active ListViewItem in WinUI

Tags: .net-core, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui-3

I'm using WinUI 3 and have a list view with rows of text. Each row has 2 buttons right aligned.

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Button 1"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Button 2"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <x:String>Hello!</x:String>
    <x:String>Hello!</x:String>
    <x:String>Hello!</x:String>
</ListView>
```

Whenever I click on an item it gets a highlight on the side.
[image: Item with highlighted side]
How do I disable the highlight? I've tried setting the `BorderBrush` of the `ListViewItem` to be transparent and that fixes it, but it ruins the alignment of the buttons:

```xml
<ListView>
   ...
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   ...
</ListView>
```

[image: Messed up alignment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove the selection indicator, you can just override `ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorVisualEnabled` and set it to `False`:

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <x:Boolean x:Key="ListViewItemSelectionIndicatorVisualEnabled">False</x:Boolean>
    </ListView.Resources>
...
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by setting `BorderBrush` to transparent and `HorizontalContentAlignment` to stretch.

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <!-- This forces the grid to stretch back out -->
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Button 1"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Button 2"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <x:String>Hello!</x:String>
    <x:String>Hello!</x:String>
    <x:String>Hello!</x:String>
</ListView>
```

Comment: What you are doing is overriding the entire default `ListViewItem` style that results in removing the indicator. So you can do this even without setting `BorderBrush` to `Transparent`. I posted an answer that shows you a direct solution.